# How to get correct API

Tags: python-2.7, api, request, scrapy

When I try to copy the url of API it gives me my email Id (username@email.com) in it, which seems not formal. see API url below:

"https://www.viu.com/api/container/load?appid=viu_desktop&iid=44be5f70-94c3-11e7-92be-c73c0c70260a&regionid=all&ver=1.0&aver=5.0&fmt=json&contentCountry=in&contentFlavour=telugu&languageid=en&platform=desktop&vuserid=u-87byqnrpcjz&userid=username@email.com&ccode=IN&geo=2&id=playlist-24911180&start=0&limit=20&geofiltered=false"

Please help me with some way where I can format (generalize) this API

Comment: The link gives me a `404` error page, https://www.viu.com/ott/misc/error/404.html. Does this API require registration and credentials with a valid email to access it? Or am I misunderstanding how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: yes it does require credential

Comment: ok thank you, seems the service is not available from my location.